# Oracle - Foreign Key creation date

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

Is there a way I can find out the date a foreign key constraint was created? I've looked in a few DBA_ views and cannot find it.

Thanks.

Gary

Comment: Is 'created' different from 'last_change'? USER_CONSTRAINTS (and the similar ALL_ and DBA_ views) has a LAST_CHANGE column (a DATE).

Comment: I think last change would track if it has been disabled/enabled, etc.